# Welcome Page change according to user is it possible in SP2010?

Tags: navigation, user

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 its a publishing site and i have different pages in the Pages folder(Which is a default one). Its a simple query i have 3 different type of users. What i want is to get a welcome page according to the type of user who logs in. For example if i'm logging in as user 1 then i should be able to see page 1 so on and so forth. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OOTB (out of the box) Functionality you could achieve that with a content query webpart which is filtered to the current user. Your pages per user of course would need some kind of property which denotes the user. However you would need to create some XSLT which renders the pages like you want them to be rendered.

A quicker solution would be to create custom code to switch the page depending on the user - again you would need some field on the page saying for which user it is.

Comment: i have 3 different sharepoint groups whose users are wanting these 3 different welcome pages. The approach you are telling me will i have to create another webpart for that or should i apply this approach to the pages' code?

Comment: As I said: use a content query webpart or do it in code. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is the same but the content is different, I would suggest to add all webparts for all users on the same page and apply audience targeting on these audience. You can create audience for SharePoint groups on the fly so you don't have to do additional stuff AD / Audience wise.

This will ensure that if the layout (eg : 25 - 50 - 25) is the same for all groups, you can safely put each similar webparts under each others in the target area and apply audience filtering on each webpart to ensure only the relevant ones will be displayed for the logged on user.

Alternatively, you could create a dummy home page with a content editor webpart in which you would add a redirect script (javascript) and apply audience on it. You copy that webpart twice so that you have 3 of them, you adapt the redirection to the relevant page and you pick the relevant audience per webpart. This will give you flexibility on the target home page will simplify the management (but this will not prevent an user from accessing a page he was not supposted to see).

Hope it helped.